# Bayesian hypothesis test to compare theta >= 1 vs. theta < 1

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bayesian

Brand new to Bayesian statistics.

I'm working a problem in R where I've used a Jeffrey's prior with a Poisson distribution to get a Gamma posterior. It's a simple problem where I've been able to compute the expectation of the posterior mean both algebraically and with a simulation in R.

I now need to do a hypothesis test with Ho being theta >= 1 and H1 being theta < 1.  Is there an easy way to do this with an R package like bayestestR, BayesTwin, Rstan etc.?  I've been looking extensively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bayesian statistics we usually do not run classical null hypothesis testing, since we cal calculate things like $\Pr(\theta \gt 1 | X)$ directly. By using Bayes theorem, you calculate the posterior probability distribution for the parameter

$$
p(\theta|X) \propto p(X|\theta) \, p(\theta)
$$

and since you know the distribution, you can calculate the probability directly. You can either calculate it by-hand, if there exist closed form solution for the posterior (when using conjugate priors), or uses MCMC simulation to calculate it. When using MCMC (most common case), $\Pr(\theta \gt 1 | X)$ is just the number of posterior samples for $\theta$ such that $\theta>1$, divided by the total number of posterior samples that you took.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Tim's answer, here are two general approaches to Bayesian hypothesis testing:

1. you can also compute the highest density interval (HDI) or set of your posterior samples and see whether or not it contains 0 (if you're testing for $\theta=0$ for example).
2. compute [Bayes factor](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes_factor), which essentially gives you a ratio of the evidence of two competing models.